reconstructing a position using angles
Given a set of points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and a target point $t\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I measure all the angles between all pairs of points and the target point. In other words, I have the angles: $\theta_{ij} = \text{angle}(p_i,t,p_j)$ for all $i,j$.
Here is the problem: The points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ and all angles $\theta_{ij}$ are given. My task is to determine whether a point $t$ that is consistent with these data exists, and if so, to provide a way of constructing it. Let's assume $n \gg d$ so the problem is overdetermined.
Here is what I have so far. I think that if I construct the matrix of angle cosines: $A_{ij} = \cos(\theta_{ij})$ then a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a consistent $t$ is that $A\succeq 0$ and $\text{rank}(A) \leq d$. I think necessity is straightforward; I'm a little less sure about sufficiency.
To reconstruct $t$, assume $A$ is PSD and rank $d$. I can start by factoring $A = V \Lambda V^\top$, where $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ and $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}_+^{d\times d}$. Then, if $v_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ column of $V^\top$, I think the factorization determines the unit directions up to an orthogonal transformation $U$:
$$
\Lambda^{1/2}v_i = U \frac{p_i - t}{\|p_i-t\|}\qquad\text{for }i=1,\dots,n.
$$
But now I'm stuck. The $\Lambda$ and $v_i$ and $p_i$ are known, and I have to find $t\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and an orthogonal $U\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ that satisfies these equations, and I'm not sure how.

Why a general $d$ and not plainly $d=2$, at least for starting ? Then, in a second step $d=3$, angles being much more difficult to handle in 3D...

I would be happy with a solution to the $d=2$ case. I only wrote the general case because I think it's likely that any method that works for $d=2$ would also work for general $d$. Maybe I'm wrong!

A possible direction of research could be to convert angular conditions into mutual distances relationship expressed by setting the Cayley-Menger determinant equal to $0$, using relationships like $\cos \theta = \frac{a^2-b^2-c^2}{2bc}$...
